# JScrollPane containing JPanel that contains smaller panels that are generated dynamically - appearing empty

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane, call it jsp. I want to populate this scroll pane with a list of strings generated dynamically. To do this, I'm creating a JPanel 'pane', and inserting into it, using a GridBagLayout (for vertical-only list), several MiniGUI's that extend JPanel (formatted like I want the output to look).

When I load up the program, jsp appears empty. I was populating it before in the same way using JTextAreas (instead of MiniGUI's) and it was working fine, but JTextArea proved terrible for formatting. I need to insert some small images to the MiniGUI's (later), which needless to say is impossible to do using JTextAreas, so I can't get rid of the MiniGUIs.

I can't seem to find the answer online, so if anyone could help it would be great. 
I checked this question out: [How do I make JScrollPane work properly with nested JPanels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193162/how-do-i-make-jscrollpane-work-properly-with-nested-jpanels), but shrinking the size of the MiniGUI didn't work, and I'm already using revalidate.

I've posted my code. The JScrollPane is about 250x500.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class MiniGUI extends JPanel {
public MiniGUI(String str1, String str2) {
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(250, 95));
    this.setVisible(true);

    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel(str1);
    lbl1.setOpaque(true);
    lbl1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    lbl1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    lbl1.setBounds(0, 0, 234, 64);
    this.add(lbl1);

    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel(str2);
    lbl2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    lbl2.setOpaque(true);
    lbl2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    lbl2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    lbl2.setBounds(86, 63, 148, 21);
    this.add(lbl2);

    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    // To be set later:
    // ImagePanel panel = img; //img passed as parameter, image panel is a class i made
    // if (img == null)
    // return;
    // panel.setBounds(0, 0, 108, 89);
    // this.add(panel);
}
```

And the function that fills the scroll pane jsp:

```
public void fillScrollPane() {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout expLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pane.setLayout(expLayout);
    ArrayList<Triplet> content = this.C2.getAL(); //C2 is another class i have, getAL returns ArrayList, Triplet is just 3 strings
    for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i += 1) {
        MiniGUI x = new MiniGUI(content.get(i).first,
                content.get(i).second + " " + content.get(i).third); //setVisible is in minigui class
        pane.add(x, c);
        pane.revalidate();
        c.gridy += 1;
    }
    MiniGUI end = new MiniGUI("", "");
    c.weighty = 1;
    pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pane.add(end, c);
    pane.setVisible(true);
    jsp.setViewportView(pane);
    jsp.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. The problem is stated, as is the code, and I spent lots of time on it before posting and still did not find a solution. If you're going to downvote, at least explain so that if there is something wrong I can fix it for next time.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you don't have a (Short, Self Contained, Correct and Compilable, Example)[http://sscce.org/] .  You have a null layout for your miniGUI.  Finally, you create a GridBagConstraints for your scroll pane panel, but you never modify it for each of your miniGUI panels.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and improve on the self-contained next time. I wasn't sure (and still am not) how to put something that is dynamically generated in an example to keep it self contained. 
But I wouldn't say the code is long, nor incorrect. As I said it worked for JTextArea, there's just some subtlety missing that I couldn't catch because I'm somewhat new to Java and GUIs. (And as such didn't see what's wrong with null layouts).
And the GridBagConstraints is modified for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `setPreferredSize()` instead of `setSize()` for your `MiniGUI`, because `setSize()` works only with null layout, but you add `MiniGUI` with help of `GridBagLayout` to your `pane`, so replace that code and it will work.

2)Don't use `this.setLayout(null);` in your `MiniGUI`. Try to use `LayoutManager`, for example `FlowLayout` or `BorderLayout` and your code also will be working.

Read more about [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Also you needn't to `revalidate()` container for each adding, do that when you add all components.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out as soon as I can.

Comment: -1, `You can use setPreferredSize() instead of setSize() for your MiniGUI`, No. Don't manually code a preferred size. The whole point of using a layout manager is to let the layout manager determine the proper size of the panel based on the number of components added to the panel. If you hard code a size then the scrollbar will never work properly.

Comment: Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to [override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513).